# Reactive way to get selectItems from a list component with changing items in angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm searching for a way to achieve this:

I have a list-view component that has a list of children in it. 
The list of children can change over time (eg because of filter)
the list-view component has an observable for the rendered items.

the children have a list-item directive attached,
that way they can be queried from the parent component by that directive, (so it doesn't matter what type of components get rendered in the list, they just need that directive applied)

the directive has an Observable selected$

How can I now get an observable inside the list-component that holds the currently selected items?

I made an example on stackblitz, for brevity my app component is the listview component here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rktm99

**update**
I'm looking for a way to combine streams to get to a stream with selected ListViewItemDirectives. The other things work, I'm stuck with this paricular thing:
I have an observable stream of contentChildren, and each child has an observable property selected$. I'm looking on how to combine those (I think I need operators like mergeMap or switchMap?)

Answer (score 0):

I guess something is wrong with the directive selector, Because,  **length** is coming **0** `this.items`

```
  @ViewChildren(ListViewItemDirective)
  items: QueryList<ListViewItemDirective>;

  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log('aaaaavvvv');
      console.log(this.items);
      }, 1000);
  }
```

Now changing the selector to

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'li'
})
```

**length** is increasing

```
QueryList {dirty: false, _results: Array[138], changes: {…}, length: 138…}
changes: EventEmitter
dirty: false
first: ListViewItemDirective
last: ListViewItemDirective
length: 138
_results: Array[138]
```

Comment: in the link in the question, just need to add null operator check in `app.component.html`; e.g.
`items selected: {{(selectedItems$|async)?.length}}` <- that will remove console.error

Comment: adding ? `items selected: {{(selectedItems$|async)?.length}}` solves the console log errors

Comment: I’m not sure I should use ngOnchanges. I have an observable for the rendered items. I want to make an observable derived from that which takes the selected$ obervable value from the children into account. The way I used map and filter gives me an observable Array of booleans but I want an observable array of directives that have selected = true

Comment: I have looked into your code, I think you should use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ContentChildren`

Comment: @VivekKumar I probably should have clarified more, what my question was. I'll update the post. I use `@contentChildren`, because in my real use-case I have content pojection, so probably view-children would be a better fit here. My question was actually on how I can combine the viewChildren/contentChildren-changes observable stream with the selected$ observable from each child-component, and return an observable of selectedItems.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i think we may have a better solution as current look like a hack.

Remove duplication in ListViewItemDirective.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[list-view-item]'
})
export class ListViewItemDirective {
  selected$: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  @Input('list-view-item') listViewItem;

  @HostBinding('class.selected')
  get isSelectedClass() {
    return this.selected$.getValue();
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  clickEvent() {
    this.selected$.next(!this.selected$.getValue());
  }
}
```

Change `ContentChildren` to `ViewChildren` and 'convert' to Observable.
When `ViewChildren` emit we will get `Observable<directive[]>` use `directiveToObservable` to get `Observable<Observable<listViewItem>[]>`.
`combineLatest` will unwrap it to `Observable<listViewItem[]>`

```
function directiveToObservable(directive) {
  return directive
    .selected$
    .pipe(map(selected => selected ? directive.listViewItem : null))
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  options = [];
  listItems = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  selectedItems$ = this.listItems.pipe(
    // hack ExpressionChangedAfterHasBeenChacked, as a changes in child will change parent
    delay(0),
    switchMap(
      directives => combineLatest(
        directives.map(directiveToObservable),
      ),
    ),
    map(list => list.filter(el => !!el)),
  );

  data$ = timer(0, 2000).pipe(
    tap((i) => this.options.push('option ' + i)),
    map(i => this.options)
  );


  @ViewChildren(ListViewItemDirective)
  set items(items: QueryList<ListViewItemDirective>) {
    this.listItems.next(items.toArray())
  }

}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wujuzg)